# nginx problem - 2 fronts with 2 different ports

Tags: nginx

I want to deploy 2 fronts (react app) with nginx and with different ports. (8080,8081).
this is my docekr-compose.yaml

summmery:
I tried many ways to deploy but I did not succeed.
It is my first time using nginx and also my first time learning things about a reverse proxy.

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.12 as build1

WORKDIR /frontend
COPY ./front1/package.json ./
COPY ./front1/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./front1/ ./
RUN npm run build


FROM node:lts-alpine3.12 as build2

WORKDIR /frontend2
COPY ./front2/package.json ./
COPY ./front2/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./front2/ ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine
COPY  ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build1 /frontend/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend1
COPY --from=build2 /frontend2/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend2
```

and this is default.conf

```
upstream front1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
upstream front2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nati.com;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend1;
        proxy_pass http://front1;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nati2.com;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend2;
        proxy_pass http://front2;
    }
}
```

tnx you !